# OFDM Symbol Duration

Tags: matlab, ofdm

The OFDM symbol duration is equal to FFT size (number of subcarriers) and guard interval according to some textbooks. However, in some research papers they mention that they implemented (using matlab) the symbol duration to be equal for example 12 µs, which is equal to 1/delta_f.
The first scenario can be implemented easily, while the other one is confusing a little bit.
My question is how we can generate an ofdm signal (in matlab) with a symbol duration equal to a value in µs (e.g., 10 µs , 12 µs, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

The time duration of each encoded symbol is $1/\Delta F$ but the time duration used to transmit each symbol is extended by the CP. So both results are valid as far as time duration for each symbol, but you must clarify if you are referring to the duration of data going into the IFFT block in the transmitter or the duration of that data after IFFT with the CP added.

In effect consider each subcarrier as a rectangular pulse shaped QAM modulated symbol of duration $1/\Delta F$ that goes to zero in between symbols.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I am using the OFDM matlab function to generate the OFDM symbol, but how can I determine the subcarrier spacing (delta_f) using that function?

Comment: Never used it- I do it in Python.

Comment: Okay, I also have never used python

Comment: We are a perfect match :)

Comment: yep.   hahahahaha

Comment: If we need to use pulse shaping filter in our simulation, where it should be added? 
Some papers they add it before parallel to serial while others use it after the parallel to serial (at the end of ofdm modulation).

Comment: oh be really careful with adding pulse shaping and for what purpose- any pulse shaping added that causes the subcarrier "symbol" to no longer be rectangular will destroy the orthogonality of the sub-carriers (ICI). In fact any subsequent filtering will do this, so just watch your achieved EVM as you limit bandwidth so that you can make that trade properly.

Comment: I think if I made T of RRC filter equal to 1/ΔF that will not cause ICI.
But still I am not sure where it should be added?
Before S/P conversion or after the modulation of the ofdm (before channel).?

Comment: Consider with any windowing other than a rectangular window where the null in the Kernel for that window will be. If the null is anywhere beyond $1/T$ you will get ICI so not sure how to pulse shape without having that happen?